# Firefox - click on image link never opens file automatically

Tags: windows-7, firefox

When I click on an image link (e.g. PNG), Firefox 4 asks me what it should do with the file, either Open With or Save File. If I check "do this automatically for files like this from now on", the next time I click the same file, it still asks the same question. How can I skip this? I just want it to open in my image viewer automatically, without asking.

EDIT: Running Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: Running Win7. I cannot delete anything from this list in SS

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using? If Windows look at file associations settings. 
You can also check your configuration for firefox by entering this in the URL location box:

```
about:config
```

Comment: what exactly would I check for?